# Skype bot responding with "Sorry, my bot code is having an issue" whereas works fine on slack or on emulator

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

I'm having trouble getting my bot to work in Skype. The only response I'm getting from the bot is "Sorry, my bot code is having an issue". I tested the bot in slack and using the MS botframework channel emulator and it's working fine there so I'm a bit perplexed why it's not responding.

It does respond if I don't LUIS to handle the response 
e.g.

```
 Activity reply = activity.CreateReply($"You sent {activity.Text} which was {length} characters");
 await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);
```

as opposed to

```
await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new someLuisDialogClass());
```

but the LUIS integrated code runs into no problems at all using Slack or the bot framework channel emulator. For the record, my Skype version is up to date and i'm using the latest version of the bot framework. Are there any changes that I need to make so that it works on Skype? Is there a way I can debug the problem so that I can get more information than "Sorry, my bot code is having an issue".

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To get more debugging information, I'd suggest using Azure Application Insights; there's a free preview that offers a lot of traffic, and we log any activity we see for your bot to your App Insights instance.

If you don't find anything useful there, we'd really need to get your bot handle to dive in and see what we can find in our logs.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have an intent method with empty string. I had the same error in my bot.  I changed one of my intent method to reflect as empty

[LuisIntent("")]